# How can I combine two conditions to override the selected row style of a datagrid?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I have a DataGrid and the objects in the collection have a property 'isvalid'  When an item is invalid (isvalid == false) I set the row foreground color to red using a data trigger.

This works, however when I select an invalid row, the selection style on the data grid row overrides the foreground color I set and it's no longer red (it just displays as the default theme foreground color).

How can I also override the foreground color style of the selected row?

I want to combine this

```
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
</Trigger>
```

With the following condition

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=isvalid}" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

A row should have foreground color red regardless if its selected or not (but only when isvalid == false)

**EDIT:**  I tried the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418664/datagrid-rows-foreground-color-for-selected-item)

```
<MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=isvalid}" Value="false" ></Condition>
</MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
```

But I get

> System.InvalidOperationException - Must have non-null value for
>   'Binding'.

Answer (score 3):

You should define a custom `CellStyle` to which you add another `DataTrigger`:

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static DataGrid.FocusBorderBrushKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                        <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding isvalid}" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridRow}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding isvalid}" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Ok thank you, I was able to achieve the same result as your code by basing the cell style on MetroDataGridCell and applying the data trigger for isvalid.  Was much less xaml.